# How to get parent view of android RemoteView used for a widget

Tags: android, widget, view

I have an android RemoteView that is inflated in a widget. Now I want to know which is the parent activity of my RemoteView. If it was a simple View, i could have used

```
(View)getParent()
```

But I did not find anything like this for RemoteViews. 
The complete archtecture uses RemoteViews only so now I cant change to Views. I hope I am clear with my query. Please help